# How do i check if an archive is passwordprotected?

Tags: .net, command-line, archive

My app is written in C# running on windows. I don't care if i am parsing a command line std out/err or using a .net lib. Lets say i have a .7z file. Its file contents are not password protected. I need to say hey, can i extract it w/o a password and need to know if the answer is yes or no WITHOUT EXTRACTING (or testing) IT.

I am currently using sevenzipsharp and unfortunately the only way to check is by attempting to extract a file. Files can be a gig or more. It would be quite some time before i'll get an answer back ATM. I tried using winrar command line interface but it only supports rar files. 7zip interface doesnt seem to tell you unless filenames are encrypted or you extract the files. Winrar you can immediately see if its encrypted but thats the windowed version, the command line didnt want look at my test zip file.

What can i use to simply check if the file is password protected? If there is a way to test if the password is correct w/o extracting that would be great but ATM not required.

Comment: Probably you have already seen it, but I have found this [discussion on codeplex](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/252706)

Comment: @Steve: Yeah but THAT is what is giving me a problem. Check extracts it and it takes FOREVER. 30+mins on 2k files. :(

Comment: just a guess here, and speaking from strictly a unix background, read the first 100? chars of file and see if there is a change in patterns between a password protected file vs plain file. Of course this technique wouldn't help with confirming good password (sorry). Also can you change compression formats? You may find that other tools (gzip, bzip2, others) have more helpful options. Else file a RFE at 7z land? Good luck